# How do I transfer an android session to web to webview securely?

Tags: android, firebase, webview, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

I tried passing user id to `webview` from URL but there is a security issue if someone gets user id then they can post data into firebase.

Is there any other way I can transfer a session to `webview`?

My current code:

```
if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            //closing this activity
            finish();
            //starting login activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }else {

            final DatabaseReference myref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            myref.child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child("data").exists()){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"You have already submitted the form",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent homeActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
                        startActivity(homeActivity);
                        finish();
                    }    else {

                        String userId = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
                        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                       // passing url parameters
                        String url = "https://someurl/?param1=" + userId;
                        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using URL variables is by far the easiest way to accomplish this.
As for security, I don't think its an issue. UserID's are impossible to guess, and it would be extremely hard for some random person to acquire it. Most users themselves don't even know their own UserID. Also you can try adding security rules to your database to help enforce security. 
You can read more about that here...

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

If you would prefer not to use this approach, you can try doing a quick google search for 'Communicating JS to native Android', but you may find it a bit complicated.